# Whats our policy on self promotion

Tags: discussion

The user 
[Pawel Kuc](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/23768/pawel-kuc) Seems to be using the SE forum as a advertisement platform. I mean his not really all that bad or very frequent, but seems to be mostly promoting his own tools. Some of the tools are free others not so much.

Anyway while I don't mind, what exactly is the limit in this case?

Comment: related, and possibly duplicate: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1014/how-to-curb-self-promotion-without-scaring-new-users-away

Comment: @Vincent true it answers the question. But what about this particular case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really see anything wrong with it. He's offering solid answers, including references to his own plugins isn't an issue in my opinion.

I didn't look at everything he's done but [How recreate the grey ellipse over a text to look like this in illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37140/how-recreate-the-grey-ellipse-over-a-text-to-look-like-this-in-illustrator/37274#37274) doesn't even mention a plugin of his.

I'd be in favor of more developers, particularly someone from Sketch coming over and answering questions about their application.

There's certainly a good way and a bad way regarding self-promotion. If you're just blatantly spamming, "Get this APP" link-only type of stuff then I'd flag it as spam. Offering a real answer that happens to use your product seems alright to me. Just like we wouldn't turn away if an Adobe employee came over and decided to answer questions here.

Comment: Ok this was my thinking, and offcourse he is up front about it. But whatabout repeating same answer in multiple places? Shouldnt the community try to merge duplicates somehow? And for obvious reasons i have nothing against developpers. Anyway i think one should also discuss alternative approaches.

Comment: This is how I feel. As long as they're stating up front that it's self promotion (and that it's actually relevant to the question), I'm fine with it.

Comment: @joojaa if they're repeating the same answer, that is indeed a good indicator that we might need to close one of the questions as duplicates.

Comment: I feel the same way. As long as the answer provides relevant content, and it's not simply duplicated.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the other post Vincent linked to this, per meta, "[Limits for self-promotion in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers)":

> May I promote products I am affiliated with here?
>
> The community generally frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to
>   vote it down and flag it as spam, so be careful. Post good, relevant
>   answers, and if they happen to be about your product, so be it.
>   However, you must disclose your affiliation with the product in your
>   answers. Also, if a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of
>   your product, you're clearly here for the wrong reasons. Our
>   advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad sales team for
>   details. We also offer free vote-based advertising for open source
>   projects.

I would suggest doing several things:

1. If you dont like the answer you're free to vote it down if you feel it's just relevant to self promotion.
2. Encourage an edit by the answeree if you think he only left enough to advertise him/herself.
3. Make an edit of the post to add more value to the answer.

If the answer in fact answers the question we tend to try and edit it.  If the user is frequent we will contact them and inform them that they must place a full disclosure in the question/answer and their profile.  If you have an issue or see it becoming a nuisance you can always flag for a moderator to review.